# Are there gases that spontaneously combust when mixed with oxygen?

Tags: molecules, combustion

Is there a known gas that would combust by there mere action of mixing with oxygen? So, we could put this hypothetical gas in a balloon, and if the balloon popped, it would combust and explode.

Comment: Phosphine - PH3

Comment: Well, any pyrophoric gas would do. Phosphine is just one of them.

Comment: @user69077 Phosphine, silane, borane.

Comment: Disilane is way more exciting than silane.

Comment: Dichlorosilane will go too

Comment: I think we have established that this is a big list question. Note that Wikipedia already has a (fairly short) list of pyrophoric materials. I can readily get over a dozen I've worked with in semiconductor processing, and asking around will yield many more, particularly when including metal organics.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Many gasses have this capability, called pyrophoric gasses. These include Phosphine, silane, borane, and more

Comment: Note that phosphine is not an element, it is a molecule.

Comment: To nitpick phosphine isn't an "element" but rather a "compound."

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I had put element.